# Spring Data REST and Spring-AMQP transaction

Tags: transactions, spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-amqp

I am using Spring Data REST with Spring-AMQP. My goal is basically to keep the atomicity between the database save made in a [POST request](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_post) handled "automatically" by Spring Data REST, and the sending of a RabbitMQ message sent by an annotated [@HandleAfterCreate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_writing_an_annotated_handler) handler, which is called after the POST request. Below the handler simplified example.

**EventHandler.java**

```
@RepositoryEventHandler
@Component
public class UserEventHandler {

    ...

    @HandleAfterCreate
    public void sendCreatedEvent(User user) {
        sendRabbitEvent("CREATED");
    }
}
```

So I ask if is there any kind of global Transaction to hold the database commit made by Spring Data REST POST to do it only after the handler successful run?

I know that if I create a controller and put it all together using the @Transactional tag, it works as expected, but I think that's not how it was supposed to work with Spring Data REST. Below is a working flow example that declares the POST in a Controller:

**Controller.java**

```
@RestController
public class MyRestController {

    ...

    @RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Transactional
    public HttpEntity<MyEntity> create(@RequestBody MyEntity myEntity) {
        // do some validations..

        // save entity
        someRepository.save(myEntity);

        // sends RabbitMQ message
        sendRabbitEvent("CREATED");

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
 }
```

With that, if the message sending fails, the contents are not saved into database. That's what I want to achieve using the handler model.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you annotate the someRepository.save() method in your repository interface with @Transactional. Would it accomplish the rollback in the event of an exception?

Comment: Hi, I believe that the @ Transactional at someRepository.save() would consider the events inside the save only. So the Event handler of @ HandleAfterCreate, which is triggered only after the  someRepository.save() is done, would be independent and wouldn't be considered part of the transaction.

Comment: I'd argue the scenario you imagine is worse than the one that's currently working. If the transaction rolls back, you – in what you ask for - end up with a message sent, that represents something at a point in time you cannot be sure the creation really works. Handle-after-create *needs* to take place *after* the creation succeeded. If you want to send messages no matter what you can also just use @HandleBeforeCreate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use transaction bound events found in spring 4.2 version.

https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2#transaction-bound-events